# binary based xmpp server?

Tags: xmpp

Helo, I'm working on a mobile game which needs realtime communication from client to server.

Usually I'll implement a TCP socket server and use some private binary protocol to enable bidirectional communication, and now I also looking into XMPP server like Ejabberd which is based on standard. But XML in some way it's really redundant and inefficient, especially for mobile app it could means more traffic and memory consumption.

1. Is it a MUST that XMPP use XML?
2. Is there any XMPP implementation that uses binary as low level data format instead of using XML? (or I shouldn't choose XMPP and start with other standard or technology.)
3. Any strategy to reduce overhead of sending complex data object (not big file object) using XMPP?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for... anything XMPP is going to use XML - otherwise it is not XMPP. Edit: apparently there IS a (joke) binary XMPP protocol: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0239.html

Comment: Sorry for not clearly and I updated the question. The protocol designers seems don't think it is an issue to use XML. in my opinion even JSON can save significant redundant traffic than XML. Based on some search Google talk API also adopt binary format if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Of course using a binary protocol has it's advantages. But it also has some major disadvantages that are solved by XMPP. In most use cases the overhead of a XML based protocol is neglectable. Don't try to optimize things when you don't really need them. Implementing a full featured chat protocol like XMPP in binary is not a trivial task. That's why no such thing exists in the open source world. And with stream compression, 'caps' and further optimization and XEPs, XMPP can be very effective even in resource constraint environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is required by the XMPP specification, so there are no binary implementations. It does indeed contain much more overhead, but you have to keep in mind the problem XMPP is designed to solve - an active chat connection can be expected to transmit maybe one message per second.

As for the Google talk api: they use a non-xml protocol for client - Google server connections. When I send a message in the Gmail client, the request body just contains a bunch of post data:

```
count=1&ofs=16&req0_type=m&req0_to=my.friend%40gmail.com&req0_id=6A8466CBC59CBB0C_0&req0_text=test&req0_chatstate=active&req0_iconset=classic&req0__sc=c
```

That part is not XMPP. The server which accepts this request then does the job of creating and sending out the XMPP requests. The XMPP is still in XML, they just use a different protocol between the client and Google server.

Comment: Thank you for providing the insight. I think it's a good strategy to reduce overhead of sending a complex data structure without touching the protocol much. That's good for MMO gaming scenario and I'll try this way.